# Slate.js - curly braces not working as mention

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slatejs

Trying to rework the [Mentions example](https://www.slatejs.org/examples/mentions) to use two curly braces (`{{`) instead of an `@` symbol for triggering the popup. Would eventually like selected text to render as:

`{{R2-D2}}` instead of `@R2-D2`.

The issue seems to be that `beforeText` is not getting the full word since the line break. For each entered text it's jumping and removing the front bracket, so the replaced regex in beforeMatch (now `beforeText.match(/^(\{{2})(\w+)$/)`) is not resolving.

**For:** `like {`
**beforeText is:** `like {`

**For:** `like {{`
**beforeText is:** `like {{`

**For:** `like {{R`
**beforeText is:** `{R`

How can I get beforeText not to jump to removing the first bracket when the first letter is entered? Have tried adding a distance option to .before() options but it's yielding the same result.